# Ruby Hash.new vs Hash literal

Tags: ruby, api, hash

I am calling a 3rd party API (written in PHP) passing in some key/value pairs.

This code works :

```
h = Hash.new
h['first_name'] = "Firstname"
h['last_name'] = "Lastname"
APICall([h]) # Record gets created
```

This doesn't :

```
h = {'first_name' => "Firstname", 'last_name' => "Lastname"}
APICall([h]) # Record does not get created
```

When I dump the Hash to the console in both the instances I get the same data structure. So why is it that the first way works but the 2nd doesn't?

**EDIT :** Not sure if this matters but I am using Ruby 1.8.7p72 / Linux . Also one of the key/value pair is a Base64 encoded image string.

Comment: There's no reason this should happen. In my tests, `Hash.object_id` returned the same value as `Hash.new.class.object_id` and `{}.class.object_id`. They're all the same class. Are you getting any errors back from the API call?

Comment: They look the same to me. If this is all of your code, I'm not sure why one would work and the other wouldn't. If this is a Rails app, I would look to see you are being affected by using a Hash where a [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) is required (this is just a hunch, if your code is as above this wouldn't be your problem).

Comment: @Brandan : unfortunately no there are no errors returned by the API.

Comment: @gar : this is a Ruby app. In theory thats all the code I have got, for the sake of brevity I have removed some key/value pairs (for eg: email etc) in my post. I too am baffled as to why the Hash created with the new method works but a hash literal doesn't

Comment: Please include plain requests to api.

Comment: @Slawosz : could you please elaborate?

Comment: Could this be an encoding issue on the strings themselves?  Can you check the encoding of each value in both types of hash?  A quick check of your sample code doesn't show any difference, but I think you've simplified down some for the purposes of the question, and the problem might be external to what you've shown here.

Comment: You have `APICall([h])`. That means that you are passing a one element array that has the hash as the only element. Is this intended?

Comment: @Anand: You need to include minimal code that really shows the issue, otherwise we can't help you (the code you included doesn't have issues). Just remove as much as possible of your original code while maintaining the problem and then post the result.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh : Yes passing one element array that has the hash is intended, the API requires it.

Comment: @Anand Please show plain http request which is generated by api call (you can inspect it by tool like wireshark). It would be nice to see if there is any difference in generated request.

Comment: @Anand: Thanks. I just wan'ted to make sure. Is there any diference in the content or how the hash is populated?

Answer (score 1):

as the documentation of class `Hash` states:

`[](*args) public`

Creates a new hash populated with the given objects. **Equivalent to the literal { key => value, … }.** In the first form, keys and values occur in pairs, so there must be an even number of arguments. The second and third form take a single argument which is either an array of key-value pairs or an object convertible to a hash.

```
Hash["a", 100, "b", 200]             #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
Hash[ [ ["a", 100], ["b", 200] ] ]   #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
Hash["a" => 100, "b" => 200]         #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
```

http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/%5B%5D/class

So at least `Hash[]` should have the same behavior as `{...}`

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: that it's possible that `Hash.new` produces something different than the literal `{..}`, because the documentation only explicitly says that `Hash[]` is equivalent to the hash literal.

Comment: Every implementation I know of produces exactly the same results for the cases described in the question.

Comment: i would also be surprised if `Hash.new` and the literal case would produce different results. the point that i want to make is that the hash-literal does not seem to be an alias of that but of `Hash[]`

Answer (score -1):

The hash literal did not come out until v1.9.  You are using v1.8.

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2009/01/30/ruby-1-9-1-released/

Search this link for "literal hash syntax":

http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_1_0/NEWS

Here is a patch to backport the feature into v1.8:

http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1183

Comment: Ruby has had hash literals since at least 1.8.6.  What's new in 1.9 is an alternate syntax for hash literals (e.g. `{foo: 'bar'}` instead of `{:foo => 'bar'}`.  The OP, however, is not using the alternate syntax.